# Pessimistic locking is not working properly with reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, locking, factory-bot

Pessimistic locking is not working properly with reload (used in the test cases). `with_lock` and `reload` is not working correctly together and test cases are getting failed. If I removed the `with_lock` then test cases work fine.

```
def method_name1
  self.with_lock do
    attributes["amount_used"] = get_total_amount_used
    attributes["updated_at"] = Time.now.utc
    Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
  end
end
```

I have written unit test cases using FactoryGirl. It calls the method_name1 which recalculate the total after the used amount. If you check the first Test case 1: total = 600 and amount_used = -200 (-ve means reducing), now total should be 400.00. Similarly for "Test case 2", After running "Test case 1" total is 400.00. amount_used = 200 (+ve means add), total should be 600.00. But Test Case 2 is saying 800.00.

```
context 'description' do
  before(:each) do
    @product.total = 600
    @product.method_name1
  end

  it 'is updated automatically if valid' do
    @product.amount_used = -200
    @product.save
    @product.reload
    should eq('400.0')       #Working
  end

  it 'is not changed if invalid' do
    @product.amount_used = 200
    @product.save
    @product.reload
    should eq('600.0')      #Not Working
  end
end
```

Error For Test Case 2:
Failure/Error: should eq('600.0')

```
   expected: "600.0"
        got: "800.0"

   (compared using ==)
```

Answer (score 1):

Test result 800 is the correct answer.

```
before(:each) do
  @product.total = 600
  @product.method_name1
end
```

`before(:each)` means this piece of code will be executed before running each example so 600 + 200 is 800. If you want it to run only once then you have to use `before(:all)` then this piece of code will run only once before running both examples.

You can see more on this in the official [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before(:each)-block).

Comment: In addition I'd like to say that the order of your tests should not matter. Always build your tests to be independent of each other.